# Function with return array values as csv

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking for simple function which will give me as output the coma separated values from array. No indexes needed...

I have an array $a=("a","b","c","d");
I need something like some_function($a);

An output should be: a,b,c,d (no comma after the last value)

I need it to mysql query. Can somebody help? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is so simple:

```
$a=("a","b","c","d");
echo implode(',', $a);
```

for more details see [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)